# How to pull the camera stream configurations?

Tags: configuration, stream

I am trying to get the stream configurations of my phone's camera. But don't know where to start..

Tried reading about how stream configurations works on Android and to build my Google camera mod, i need to pull the right stream configurations but i can't find how.